# Gateways of interfaces NOT active

Tags: gateway

I 've configured two static interfaces which are active.
For each interface I have configured a gateway.
However these gateways do not show up in the active configuration (Webmin) or cli-command `route`.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

default 10.16.0.254     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens160

10.16.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160

172.16.0.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
```

If I do a traceroute from int ens192 to 10.16.0.17 (my pc) it will not show the first hop which should be 172.16.0.254 which is my L3 switch.

```
traceroute -i ens192 10.16.0.17

traceroute to 10.16.0.17 (10.16.0.17), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanx Jaap
(newbie)